# prove exactly 2 base p decimal expansions

Tags: analysis

In the following proof, there are 3 things I don't understand. Can anyone help me out with any of the 3?

**Question :**

Let $p≥2$ be a fixed integer,and let $0<x<1$. If $x$ has a finite-length base $p$ decimal expansion, that is,if $x=\frac{a1} {p}+...+\frac{an}{p^n}$ with $a_n ≠0$, prove that x has
precisely two base $p$ decimal expansions. Otherwise, show that the base $p$ decimal expansion for $x$ is unique.

**Proof** :

$$\text{Suppose } x=\frac{a1}{p}+...+\frac{a_n}{p^n},\\ \text{then }x=\frac{a_1}{p}+...+\frac{a_{n-1}}{p^n}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p^i}$$

Let $0.b_1b_2...b_n...$ and $0.c_1c_2...c_n...$ be any two base $p$ decimal expansions for $x$ and suppose n is the first integer for which $b_i \neq c_i$. Then, without loss of generality, $b_1=c_1, b_2=c_2, ..., b_{n-1}=c_{n-1}, b_n<c_n$. Thus

$$
0.b_1b_2...b_n... = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{b_i}{p^i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{p^i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\frac{p-1}{p^i}=
\\\frac{b_1}{p}+\frac{b_2}{p^2}+...+\frac{b_{n}+1}{p^n} \leq \frac{c_1}{p}+\frac{c_2}{p^2}+..+\frac{c_n}{p^n} \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{c_i}{p^i}=0.c_1c_2...c_n...
$$
With equality if and only if $b_{n+i}=p-1, c_n=b_n+1$, and $c_{n+i}=0\, \forall \, i \, \geq 1 $.

This means that if $x$ has two decimal expansions, one of them must be finite. Hence if $x$ does not have a finite decimal expansion (mod $p$), its representation is unique.

**What I don't understand :**

(1) why is this true : $x=\frac{a1}{p}+...+\frac{a_n}{p^n}=\frac{a_1}{p}+...+\frac{a_{n-1}}{p^n}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{p-1}{p^i}$

(2) If the above is true, where does the $\leq$ symbol come from in this statement : $0.b_1b_2...b_n... = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{b_i}{p^i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{p^i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\frac{p-1}{p^i}$

(3) The proof states that the inequality above becomes equal if $b_{n+i}=p-1$, but when I plug that in it does not become equal :  $0.b_1b_2...b_n... = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{b_i}{p^i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{p^i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\frac{b_{n+i}}{p^i}$ at $i=n+1$, $\frac{b_{n+i}}{p^i}=\frac{b_{n+n+1}}{p^{n+1}}$. So its not equal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going on is the same as in base $10$ where a terminating decimal has two representations, the usual one with all $0$s after the end and the other where you decrease the last digit by $1$ and add a string of $9$s. For example,
$$0.125=0.124999999\ldots$$
For (1) in the second line of your proof it should be $\frac {a_n-1}{p^n}+\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\frac {p-1}{p^i}$.  That shows the decrease in the last digit of the terminating decimal and appending the string of $p-1$'s  The point is that the infinite sum is a geometric progression that adds to $\frac 1{p^n}$

For (2) you have a typo where it should be $b_i \neq c_i$.  The inequality you ask about just has all the digits of $b$ rounded up to $p-1$, so it must be greater.

For (3) the term you write as $\frac {b_{n+1}}{p^n}$ should be $\frac {b_n+1}{p^n}$ and it is equal when $c_n=b_n+1$ with the other conditions.